# Как отключить в intellij idea выполнение тестов?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven

Как отключить в intellij idea выполнение тестов при запуске проекта Maven командой Run из ее меню. 
Подробнее. Проект на основе Mavena.
Проект запускается командой Run самой Идеи. (Run--Run "имя проекта").
В качестве стартера в окне "Run/Debug Configuration" выбран Tomcat.
И вопрос: в каких настройках идеи можно отключить выполнение тестов при построении (или деплое)?
Отключение  тестирования в окне Maven Projects не помогло.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: команда `Run` вроде как запускает соответствующую конфигурацию, в которой должна быть указана строка запуска. думаю добавление в строку запуска `-DskipTests` поможет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если используете Local Tomcat Server, то добавьте:

```
 -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

в Edit Configurations -> VM Options

Если используете плагин tomcat: 
Edit Configurations -> Runner -> Skip Tests
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В Edit Configurations (Run/Debug Configuration: Tomcat Server) Runner`a найти не смог. А в Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment->Maven->Runner->Skip Tests стоит, но не работает

Comment: Добавил скрин, всё-ещё не неходится?

Comment: Естественно нет -). Я привык использовать для запуска конфигурацию на основе локального Tomcat сервера. Там вкладки Runner нет. Ну что же попробую запускать так. Но все таки хотелось бы узнать, как запускать проект без тестирования под Tomcat`ом.

Comment: Покажите ваш конфиг.

Comment: Попробуйте -Dmaven.test.skip=true

Comment: `Попробуйте -Dmaven.test.skip=true` А этот параметр для кого?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62965/discussion-between---and--).